# Using XCode 4.3.3 to build apps for pre IOS 5.0 users

Tags: ios, xcode

My apologies if this question has been asked before. I can see there are a lot of questions that appear similar, however it seems they are mainly asking to do the reverse of what I am asking here.

I took a break from developing for a few months, because I had sold my macBook, and in the meantime upgraded my iPhone 4 to IOS 5.1 (over wifi)

Before selling the macbook, I made a carbon copy of my drive and made sure it could be booted and used to maintain things (on a borrowed mac).

Anyway I am now back on line with a second hand macbook classic, which came with a fresh Lion install, and whilst the workstation backup drive I made boots up fine, I discovered to my dismay that Xcode 4.2 no longer lets me build to my iPhone, so I had to go ahead and install XCode 4.3.3 Under Lion. 6GB of update downloads and installs later, all is well, however I am now left with a puzzling question.

If I make a new app, it appears to be an IOS 5.1 app, and the only simulator available is IOS 5.1 iPhone and IOS 5.1 iPad. and of course my iPhone device.

so... if I go ahead and submit this app to the app store, (ensuring I don't use any 5.1 specific features), does this mean users with versions of IOS lower than 5.x can still download and deploy the app? I can't test it as there are no simulators, and I only have access to 5.1 installed devices. I tried downloading additional simulators, but the default new project seems to preclude them from the menu system.

What is the best way to make one (1) app that everybody (including 5.x users) can download? 
I would have stayed with Xcode 4.2 but this would mean having to trash my iPhone to do device testing.

Alternatively is there some way of going back to my original workstation (4.2) and configure it to allow me to do device testing on my 5.1 device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode, select the project file in the project navigator, and then the target. In the first section of the "Summary" tab you have "iOS Application Target". There you can choose earlier iOS versions.

That's all.

Comment: An embarrassingly easy solution a newbie should have known. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In xcode go to preferences `command + ","` navigate to downloads. choose components tab, and you will find the ios simulators, download the one you wish from there

Comment: Thanks Omar. I had done that, however they weren't being offered until I applied Mundi's solution. I forget with all the Interface changes in the various Xcode versions where things get configured etc. All is good now though :)